# Complex Integration Question : Integrate $f(z) = x^2+iy^2$ when $z(t) = t^2+it^2$ and $0 \le t \le 1$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration, parametrization, cauchy-integral-formula

I'm trying to integrate this as a definite integral.
$f(z) = x^2+iy^2$ when $z(t) = t^2+it^2$ and $0 \le t \le 1$.

I know that:

$$\int_{z(a)}^{z(b) }f[z(t)]z'(t) \,dt= \int_C f(z) dz$$

I'm confused on how to parametrize the $x$ and $y$ terms in the $f(z)$ function and complete the integration:

$$\int_0^{(1+it)} f[z(t)]z'(t) \,dt= \int_C x^2+iy^2 dz$$

---

EDIT:

So this is what I have so far. From, $z(t) = t^2+it^2$ and $0 \le t \le 1$,

$x(t) = t^2$ an $y(t) = t^2$

I think we need to substitute these values in for $x^2+iy^2$

So we would have
$$f(z(t)) = [(t^2)^2+i(t^2)^2] $$
$$z'(t) = 4t^3+ 4it^3$$
$$\int_C x^2+iy^2 = \int_0^1 f(z(t))(z'(t))dt = \int_0^1 [(t^2)^2+i(t^2)^2][4t^3+ 4it^3]dt $$

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the confusing thing is the definition of $f$, it is the map $x+iy\mapsto x^2+iy^2$, where $x=\operatorname{Re}(z)$ and $y=\operatorname{Im}(z)$, then you have that $(f\circ z)(t)=(t^2)^2+i(t^2)^2=t^4(1+i)$, and
$$
dz(t)=d(t^2+it^2)=2tdt+2itdt=2t(1+i)dt
$$
Then, assuming that $C$ is the curve parametrized by $z$, we have that
$$
\int_{C}f(z)dz=\int_{0}^1 (f\circ z)(t)dz(t)=\int_0^{1}2t^5(1+i)^2dt=(1+i)^2\cdot \frac1{3}=i\frac2{3}
$$